# Using WIF STS tokens with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wif

I have recently finished creating a STS setup and need to expose some WCF service methods on the STS's themselves. So far the login sends a token to the claims provider, the claims provider sets all the clams and then hands the user back down to the front end so that's working fine. I need to implement some WCF functions that need to check that the user has a valid token to trigger the method. I have looked into it and have tried configuring WSFederationHttpBind with little success. It seems to ask the client for a certificate via "Windows cardspace" for some reason and I can't find a way to assign the already produced token with the WCF call from the client. Any pointers in the right direction would be great I've been racking my brains all day and clearly not searching for the right thing!

P.S The STS uses WIF to create/assign the tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "It seems to ask the client for a certificate via "Windows cardspace" for some reason" do you mean that when the client calls the service operation you get a UI for CardSpace asking the user to select some credentials?

If so, to suppress this you need to set

channelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;

Answer (score 1):

A simple sample is avaialble in the WIF SDK. A slightly more complex one is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359113.aspx

Comment: Thats one of the web pages I've used as reference, perhaps the problem is something else other than mis-configuration. Hmmm.